# Convert char* array of integers to hex

Tags: c++

I have a struct that stores the integer value as a custom string type.

```
typedef char OneLine[MAX_LINE + 1];
```

So I have some instances where I want the string that contains **"12"** to be converted to 
**C**.

```
OneLine testString;
strcpy(testString, "12");

I'd like a way for me to convert testString to be "C"
```

How should I tackle this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason why you are storing integers as strings? It would be easier if you store them as integers.

Comment: It's part of a larger assignment for a systems programming course. Data types were chosen by the professor. I guess figuring out this problem was part of the assignment objectives but I was getting too frustrated with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sscanf` to convert "12" to an integer 12.  Then you can use `sprintf` with `%x` format to convert integer 12 to "C"

Comment: sprintf is pretty unsafe (output buffer can overflow).

Comment: @user1610015, right, for real applications use the safe version `snprintf`.  Although I don't know how you can make %x cause an overflow.  The main risk would be if you used %s

Answer (score 1):

The conversion can be done using stringstreams

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <ios>

int main()
{
  char const *str = "12";
  std::istringstream iss( str );
  int val;

  if( !( iss >> val ) ) { 
    // handle error 
  }
  std::ostringstream oss;

  oss << std::hex << val;
  std::cout << oss.str() << std::endl;
}
```

---

Or  slightly less verbose way with C++11

```
char const *str = "12";
auto val = std::stoi( str );

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << std::hex << val;
std::cout << oss.str() << std::endl;
```

Comment: +1 beat me by one second. Also, you do not need to include `<iomanip>` for `std::hex`.

Comment: @JesseGood Hmm, you're right, `std::hex` is defined in `ios`, not `iomanip`

Answer (score 0):

First, even if you were to do this manually, you shouldn't use char arrays for strings. Use `std::[w]string`.

Second, you can do this with `std::[w][i|o]stringstream`:

```
istringstream iss("12");
int number;
iss >> number;

ostringstream oss;
oss << hex << number;

const string& hexNumber = oss.str();
// hexNumber now contains "C"
```

Comment: I really wish I didn't have to. My professor required us to for a series of assignments. I would've much rather used a standard cstring for most of the work. Thanks for your input!

Comment: No reason to use `const string&`, I would make that `string` or `const string`. Also, hexNumber contains a lowercase c. You need `oss << hex << uppercase << number` for uppercase.

Comment: @JesseGood Using `const string&` avoids a copy. You're right about std::uppercase, I was reading a faulty docs site that said that uppercase letters was the default.

Comment: Don't try to be smarter than the compiler (refer to [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)), the copy will be most likely elided. Also, a const ref is non-modifiable so the object cannot be reused (plus we are talking about avoiding a copy for two characters...).